# Chaining multiple coaxial adapters

Tags: antenna, rtl-sdr

I want to connect an RTL-SDR dongle that has an MCX Female antenna port to an N-Type Male antenna feedline. I know there are thousands of pigtails and adapters for every possible need, seemingly except this one.

I've searched the usual places and can't find an MCX Male to N-Type Male adapter.

Can I use more than one adapter inline to make this connection happen? And if so, what would be the best combination? Some signal loss is acceptable.

Comment: Amazon sells all kinds of cables, I use them in a pinch. [Here](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00CSFCCYW) is the one you want. Also eBay if you have more time. But chaining adapters is pretty standard too, just get everything-to-sma.

Comment: Also, consider investing the $30 in a RTL-SDR-blog v3 stick, with an SMA. The MCX one I had was fun but just not as good. ymmv.

Comment: @tomnexus funny how days of searching didn't turn up that item. Thanks for the link, and for the suggestion to choose a different device.

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you are having difficulty finding an adapter is because the N connector is heavy and the extra weight will stress out the MCX connector and probably break it eventually.

Instead, you want to get a "pigtail" style adapter with a short piece of coax between the two so that the coax bends instead of stressing the MCX.

I have found adapters for this at hamfests (I have one in my kit), but they are rare.  You could also just buy the parts and make one.